# How can I scrape data from a chart using Cheerio?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a chat, but I don't know how to do that using Cheerio in NodeJs

I need to get all nicknames(msg-nickname) of the list of messages:

[image]

So far I have:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

url = 'https://www.nimo.tv/live/6865137196';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var nickname, msg;
    var json = { nickname : "", msg : ""};
    const messages = [];

    $('.msg-nickname',).each(function(i, elem){
        console.log(elem);
        messages[i] = elem.parent.children.text();
    })

    console.log($('#chat-room__list').children('msg-wrap').text)

    
}

app.listen('8081') 
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081'); 
exports = module.exports = app;
```

And I also need to update be checking and updating the list every time you have a new item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that that part of the code `.msg-nickname` is generated on the client side. So if you want to scrape it, you will need to know from what request that data is coming from, and execute that request instead.

**cheerio** can only parse, what's coming in the request response.

The other alternative is to use `puppeteer` which will allow you to wait until the page is fully loaded, including server side rendering, ajax requests...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(url);

        // waitForSelector can be added, depending on your needs
        // but if there isn't any user, it will wait until it timesout
        // which may not be desired
        // await page.waitForSelector('.msg-nickname');

        const messages = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.msg-nickname'))
                        .map(item => item.innerText);
        });

        console.log(messages);
})();
```

Depending on how the nick names are loaded, you may need to hook into `page.on('response')`, or change the logic of the script, but I leave that to you.

Comment: How about using this line `await page.waitFor('.msg-nickname');` in order to make sure the page is duly loaded?

Comment: The thing is, that that selector don't always exists, if there is no user connected, it will wait until it timesout, making the script much slower. Each scraper is unique, so sometimes you want to use `await page.waitForSelector('.msg-nickname')`, sometimes you don't, in this case, it's better if you don't do it.

Comment: I added the comment to the code, but for this case is not needed.

Comment: you know how I could make this script run, checking if there is a new item, if you have a new item and if you have a new item, you can capture it to the list;
as if it were a realtime capture of the chat inputs

Comment: Yo will need to run it at intervals and push to messages, probably using websockets instead of an http request like you're doing.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the answer! I'm going to study more to do that